# Algebraic Set and Lattice Points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is from my quiz in Algebraic Geometry( which was over today). The following question was one of the question asked in quiz. I couldn't solve it during exam time and as I tried it today at home and still couldn't made any progress.

> Question :  If $\mathbb{Z}^n =\{(a_1,...,a_n) \mid a_i \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for every } i=1,..., n\}$ be the set  of lattice points.  If $L$ is an algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{Z}^n \subseteq V$, then $V=\mathbb{C}^n$

Attempt: L is algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ means that $L=V(S)$ for some $S$ in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ where $V(S)=\{ p\in \mathbb{C}^n \mid f(p)=0 \text{ for all } f\in S\}$. It is given that $\mathbb{Z}^n \subseteq L$. $L$ will be always a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$. I tried by assuming that let $L$ be a proper set of $\mathbb{C}^n$, in the hope of getting some contradiction. But unfortunately, I am not able to think what result should  I use to proceed.

Kindly give a few hints.

Comment: Can you solve it when $n=1$?

Comment: Hint: $V(I(\mathbb{Z}^n))$ is the zariski closure of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. What is $I(\mathbb{Z}^n)$?

Answer (score 1):

By induction on the dimension.

In $\mathbb{A}^1_k$, the topology is the cofinite topology and the integers are infinite. Therefore any closed set containing the integers is all of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.

Now, suppose the result is true for $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}_k$. We want to prove it's true for $\mathbb{A}^n_k$. Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and consider the set $Z_{i, a} = \{x_1, ... x_n \in \mathbb{A}^n_k : x_i = a\}$. This is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{n-1}_k$, and by the induction hypothesis, any polynomial that vanishes on the lattice points must vanish on all of $Z_{i, a}$. Furthermore, note that $Z_{i, a}$ is irreducible of dimension $n-1$.

Let $I =  I(\mathbb{Z}^n)$. Then, any $f \in I$ vanishes on $Z_{i, a}$ for all $i \in \{1, ... n \}, a \in \mathbb{Z}$. What is the dimension of $V(I)$? It must be at least $n-1$, since $V(I)$ contains $Z_{i, a}$ which has dimension $n-1$. Since the $Z_{i, a}$ are irreducible, if $V(I)$ has dimension equal to $n-1$ then $Z_{i, a}$ would be irreducible components. This implies $V(f)$ has infinitely many irreducible components, a contradiction. Therefore, $V(I)$ has dimension $n$.

The only dimension $n$ set in $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ is all of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$, so $V(I) = \mathbb{A}^n_k$.

Comment: How you are sure that the topology on $\mathbb{A}_{k}^{1}$ is co-finite topology?

Comment: @Avenger Let $S$ be a closed set. Then $S = V(I)$ for some ideal $I \subseteq k[x]$. Since $k[x]$ is Noetherian, $I = (f_1, ... f_n)$. Then, $a \in V(I)$ iff $f_1(a), ... f_n(a)$ are all 0. A polynomial only has finitely many roots, so every closed set is finite. Conversely, singleton sets are closed since they are the root of $x-a$, so finite sets are closed.

Comment: How does S being close implies that S=V(I) for some ideal I ?

Comment: By definition of closed set, closed sets are the sets of the form $V(I)$.

Comment: Thanks! I have asked a lot of other questions on algebraic geometry and they are unanswered. I am from a really poor region of the world and I shall be grateful if you can answer some of those!